# How to compare two proto buffer message in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

In package `com.google.protobuf` I found a `Message` interface, it claims it will compare by content:

```
public interface Message extends MessageLite, MessageOrBuilder {
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Comparison and hashing

  /**
   * Compares the specified object with this message for equality.  Returns
   * <tt>true</tt> if the given object is a message of the same type (as
   * defined by {@code getDescriptorForType()}) and has identical values for
   * all of its fields.  Subclasses must implement this; inheriting
   * {@code Object.equals()} is incorrect.
   *
   * @param other object to be compared for equality with this message
   * @return <tt>true</tt> if the specified object is equal to this message
   */
  @Override
  boolean equals(Object other);
```

But I write test code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    UserMidMessage.UserMid.Builder aBuilder = UserMidMessage.UserMid.newBuilder();
    aBuilder.setQuery("aaa");
    aBuilder.setCateId("bbb");
    aBuilder.setType(UserMidMessage.Type.BROWSE);
    System.out.println(aBuilder.build() == aBuilder.build());        
  }
}
```

It gives `false`.

So, how to compare to proto buffer message?

Comment: If you want to call `equals`, you should do exactly that - you're currently using `==` instead...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`==` compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the **same object** (*not equivalent objects, **the same object***), so you can be sure that **`.build()` makes a new object each time**...

To use the code you posted you must compare with `equals`

```
System.out.println(aBuilder.build().equals(aBuilder.build()));
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you need to compare objects with the `equals` method, not with the `==` operator. The problem is that `==` compares if it is the same object, whereas the `equals` method compares if they are equal with the provided implementation by the developer of the class.

```
System.out.println(aBuilder.build().equals(aBuilder.build()));
```

For more details, there are tons of questions about this already (for example [Java == vs equals() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion).